# Convenient Notations for Free Abelian Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, free-groups, free-abelian-group

Is there a convenient (and commonly used) notation for Free Abelian Group?

For instance, the free abelian group generated by two elements: $\langle a,b\mid ab=ba\rangle$, it seems quite unwieldy to keep writing this.

Also, I wish to keep track of the generators, $a,b$, hence something like $F_2$ is not suitable.

I have seen something like $\mathbb{Z}\{a,b\}$, but not sure if it standard? Are there any other possibilities? I am quite new to this subject.

Thanks!

Comment: A notation is $\mathbb{Z}^{(X)}$, where $X$ is a basis.

Comment: @egreg Thanks. Can you provide a reference where this notation is used?

Comment: Fuchs' books “Infinite abelian groups”, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to isomorphism, the free abelian group generated by $n$ elements is $\mathbb Z^n$. If you want to keep track of generators, some standard notations are
$$
\mathbb Za_1+\cdots +\mathbb Za_n
$$
and
$$
\langle a_1,\ldots,a_n\rangle
$$
and
$$
\mathbb Za_1\oplus \cdots\oplus \mathbb Z a_n,
$$
where the group has been written as a direct sum of its infinite cyclic subgroups $\mathbb Z a_1=\langle a_1\rangle$ up through $\mathbb Z a_n=\langle a_n\rangle$.

Since abelian groups are the same thing as $\mathbb Z$-modules, many of these notations are special cases of notation used more generally for direct sums and direct products of $R$-modules, where $R$ is a ring.